# Division using Sum does not work

Tags: c#, sum, division

In my program, I created a list of a custom class. This class contains a integer property. I want to divide an other given integer by the sum of these properties in my list - but `Sum()` does not seam to work properly in divisions.

I created a short demo for you, it's a simple console application:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Sum
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Class> list = new List<Class>() {
                new Class() { Property = 1},
                new Class() { Property = 1},
                new Class() { Property = 1},
                new Class() { Property = 1},
                new Class() { Property = 1},
                new Class() { Property = 1}
            };

            Console.WriteLine("Sum: " + list.Sum(x => x.Property));
            Console.WriteLine("Division: " + (2 / list.Sum(x => x.Property)));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Class
    {
        public int Property { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I know that I could save the sum of the properties in a new variable and use it afterwards for my division. But shouldn't `Sum` should work successful in this situation?

Comment: You are using a Integer division rather than a floating point division.

Comment: [Integer division](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa691373.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're using integer division, not floating-point division. Try using `2f` instead to a [`float`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx) constant:

```
Console.WriteLine("Division: " + (2f / list.Sum(x => x.Property)));
```

Or `2d` instead to a [`double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx) constant:

```
Console.WriteLine("Division: " + (2d / list.Sum(x => x.Property)));
```

Or `2m` instead to a [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) constant:

```
Console.WriteLine("Division: " + (2m / list.Sum(x => x.Property)));
```

Any one will give you the result you're looking for (with only some difference in accuracy)

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is you are using integer division which supports whole numbers only.  You want instead to do floating point division which supports decimals

```
Console.WriteLine("Division: " + ((double)2 / list.Sum(x => x.Property)));
```

Answer (score 2):

`Sum` actually work, but result is `0` because you use integer division: `int` divides `int` => result will be `int`, you should change:

```
(2.0 / list.Sum(x => x.Property))
```

It will work

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you expect the result to be `2 / 6 = 0,33` but integer division always result in an integer (in C#). So at least one number must be a floating point type like `double`.

```
Console.WriteLine("Division: " + (2d / list.Sum(x => x.Property)));
```

> The division rounds the result towards zero, and the absolute value of
>   the result is the largest possible integer that is less than the
>   absolute value of the quotient of the two operands. The result is zero
>   or positive when the two operands have the same sign and zero or
>   negative when the two operands have opposite signs.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691373(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think it will write 0 to the output, because of the integer division.